# What is the correspondent to dependent?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correspondent to dependent?

As in:
"Child" is to "parent" as "dependent" is to _____

Context:
"The ______ task must be completed before any of its dependent tasks can be started."

Comment: Is this for IT?

Comment: Could be, but more for procedural documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context, I think, it's ***PRIMARY***.

It's not the opposite of 'dependent' but it can be appropriate here.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/primary:

***PRIMARY***

: of first rank, importance, or value

:PRINCIPAL

// the primary
purpose

: belonging to the first group or order in successive divisions, combinations, or ramifications

// primary nerves

Comment: ah, yes, that makes sense. Using your suggestion as a reference, I think another option would be 'principal.   
`
**principal**   
[1]: most important, consequential, or influential : chief the principal ingredient the region's principal city.  
[2]: of, relating to, or constituting principal or a principal
`

Answer (score -1):

In the context of a child being a dependent, I would think of the parent as the provider. Context is everything here.